# javascript/angularjs looping through an array show only one object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in angularjs  modal i am trying to display all classes that have level 4 but i got only one. please how should i alter my could in order to get all the class

```
$scope.openClass = function (classes) {
    $log.info("classes",classes);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'classes.html',
        controller: 'ModalClassInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            info: function () {
                var info = {};
                for (var i=0;i<classes.length;i++){                     
                    if (classes[i].level==4){                           
                        info['name']= classes[i].name;
                        $log.info("classinfo",info);                            
                    }
                }                   
                $log.info(info);
                return info;
            }
    }
});
```

the $log in if condition show me the write classes they are two in my case but the $log after the for loop show me only one

Comment: First of all, you should add `var` in your `for` loop. Without it, it assumes that `i`is a global variable. And if using anyway in the script anothervariable named `i`, you'll have some unexpected results.

Comment: And it constantly overwrites info['name'] in this code, so you'll only get 1 result.

Comment: i have added var to my for but how can i prevent it from overwrites , i tried to use break; but it just break after the object and never continue

Comment: Ofcourse it will stop when you call it to stop.
Probably do something like `info[]['name']` or `info['name'].push(classes[i].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [filter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method, as the following:

```
var filteredArray = classes.filter(function(value) {
   return value.level == 4;
));
```

After it, if you want to *pluck* only the name of those items you can do the following:

```
var names = filteredArray.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.name;
}
```

If you are going to do this often, you could write a function that abstracts away the map, this way:

```
function pluck(array, key) {
  return array.map(function(item) {
    return item[key]; 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: thanks developer033  the filteredArray is what i want thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think, you overwrite you param "name"

```
info['name']= classes[i].name;
```

If you want collection, you should

```
var info = [];
info.push(classes[i].name)
```